# MS Access query returning 0 count in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm having difficulty with a MS Access 2010 query. I have a table that roughly has the following fields: ID (*AutoIncrement*), ACRES (*Number*), VOLUME (*Number*), BEGIN_DATE (*Date/Time*), CONTRACT_AMT (*Currency*), COLLECTED_AMT (*Currency*).

I then created a query table that calculated a field with the fiscal year (July 1 to June 30) of the BEGIN_DATE using this expression:

```sql
FYBegin: IIf([CalendarMonthBegin] Between 7 And 12,[CalendarYearBegin]+1,
[CalendarYearBegin])
```

What I need to do now is create a query that counts the ID's, and sums the volume, acres, contract, and collected amounts that are in this fiscal year.

I created the following VBA function to get the current fiscal year:

```vb
Public Function GetCurrentFiscalYear(ByVal CurrentDate As Date)
'Returns the current fiscal year for CurrentFY_Summary query

Dim yearToday As Integer
Dim monthToday As Integer
Dim currentFiscalYear As Integer

yearToday = Year(CurrentDate)
Debug.Print (yearToday)
monthToday = Month(CurrentDate)
Debug.Print (monthToday)

If monthToday > 6 And monthToday < 13 Then
    currentFiscalYear = yearToday + 1
    Debug.Print (currentFiscalYear)
Else
    currentFiscalYear = yearToday
    Debug.Print (currentFiscalYear)
End If
End Function
```

But when I try to create another query using the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT Count(FiscalYear.ID) AS [Count of Records], Sum(FiscalYear.ACRES) AS 
[Sum Of ACRES], Sum(FiscalYear.VOLUME) AS [Sum Of VOLUME], 
Sum(FiscalYear.CONTRACT_AMT) AS [Sum Of CONTRACT_AMT], 
Sum(FiscalYear.COLLECTED_AMT) AS [Sum Of COLLECTED_AMT]
FROM FiscalYear
WHERE (FiscalYear.FYBegin) = GetCurrentFiscalYear(Now());
```

I just get a 0 in the count field and no other records. I can visually see that records match the criteria and I used the immediate window to verify that the VBA function is returning the correct fiscal year and as an integer. What is incorrect about the SQL statement and/or VBA function.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Debug.Print` commands are fooling you in this case. They print internal variables, but not the function return value.

Your function is missing this line:

```vb
GetCurrentFiscalYear = currentFiscalYear
```

otherwise it will always return NULL.